# Avoid recycling of the items in the Recyclerview

Tags: android

I have a recycler view which contains different types of views. There are only 8 items in the recycler view and i don't want to recycle those views on scrolling. How to disable the recycling feature of the recycler view? 
Or is there any better method to approach this?

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to recycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using ScrollView instead? You could include the different layout types you want to use inside the ScrollView, and there you would not get recycling behavior.

If that is not good enough, than I would sudgest to stick with recycler view, and not worry about views getting recycled, because it is not much of a big deal.

But if you are still convinced that you need a recycler view without the recycling behavior, you could try `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);` on every viewholder instantiation, that way they won't get recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Set the below line in your activity

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(1,0);
```

set Below Code in RecyclerViewAdapter class

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Yah sorry, Due to You have a different type of views it will not work,,,,,In your getItemViewType(int position) method of adapter, assign unique values for each view holder